# how to disable unicode id creaton and put lenght restriction on id creation on register API

Tags: api, ejabberd

how to disable Unicode id creation and put length restriction on id creation on register API? 
for exmple: when users try to register an account they cant use less than 5 letters and more than 32 letters to creat their accounts.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add details of how can we reproduce what you get, show what you get, and show what you would like to get instead?

Comment: i hope this is better then the last one. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are the accounts being created by XMPP clients, using mod_register? Then you can configure it like this, to disallow registration of usernames as you mentioned:

```
acl:
  shortname:
    user_regexp:
      - "^.{0,5}$"
  longname:
    user_regexp:
      - "^.{33,}$"

access_rules:
  register:
    - deny: shortname
    - deny: longname
    - allow: all

modules:
  mod_register:
    access: register
```

But instead, if the users to register their accounts are calling the "register" admin API command, that command bypasses that restriction, so it cannot be restricted.